# Multiple CASE/WHEN with substr

Tags: oracle, case, substr

NOTE: This is the final answer, ideally we shouldn't be updating original question, Thanks Alex P for pointing out.

How can we use multiple case... when with substr in Oracle?

```
Table (T1):
Hostname  Value
H1        oracleDB1 (local x)
H2        oracleDB2 (local y)
H3        congo/db/abc
H4        congo/db/def
H5        other/rsync

Query: *SELECT hostname, 
           CASE
           WHEN value like ('%oracle%')
           THEN substr(value, 7,instr(value, ' ')-7)  // get value = DB1, DB2..
           WHEN value like ('%congo%')
           THEN value = 'congo'                      //get value = congo
           ELSE
           substr(value, 1,5)  // get first 5 character
           END AS value
        FROM T1;*

Expected Result:
H1   DB1
H2   DB2
H3   congo
H4   congo
H5   other
```

I think my fist substr is wrong since it give me oracleDB1 instead of just DB1, can someone please just correct way to handle this?

Comment: Well your first substr is always starting at character 1, not after the 'oracle' part; your like condition is wildcarded both ends though, so are you expecting something more complicated too, like 'x oracleDB3 y`? And why does your second substr have the instr call, rather than the fixed value of 5? Do you really want five characters, or everything up to the first /?

Comment: Thanks Alex, for first substr I'm trying to start from 7th character till it reaches empty space sample data "oracleDB1 (local x)", for second substr I think I can use substr(value,1,5)

Comment: OK, but you're currently starting from the first character, as you've given the second argument as 1 instead of 7?

Comment: Ohh yes, updated that to 7, how can I restrict till empty space? currently it continues till end, getting "DB1 (LOCA" instead of "DB1"

Comment: You're also missing a comma after `value v`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're currently doing:

```
substr(value, 1, instr(value, ' ') - 1)
```

Which gives you the substring that starts at the first character, and is `instr(value, ' '), - 1` characters long. So for `oracleDB1 (local x)`, the first space is character 10, so you're getting the 9 characters starting at position 1.

If you just change the starting position to 7 to skip the fixed `'oracle'` part:

```
substr(value, 7, instr(value, ' ') - 1)
```

then you'll the 9 characters starting at position 1, which is `DB1 (LOCA`. Remember [the third argument is the length](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions181.htm), it isn't the end position. So now you need to take the length of the fixed `oracle` part into account again, and reduce the length you're looking for by that amount too:

```
substr(value, 7, instr(value, ' ') - 7)
```

Or spelling out where the values are coming from:

```
substr(value, length('oracle') + 1, instr(value, ' ') - (length('oracle') + 1))
```

Comment: great... works like charm, can you suggest correct way to use case in select clause, tried different variation but nothing seems to work for case... when ... then .. else ?

Comment: Thanks, got it working,, updated original request so that other can use it.

Comment: It isn't helpful to change the question like that - now it doesn't look like there was ever a problem...

Comment: my bad, I will remember not to do in future.